# How to group by the each week upto last six week sundays dates in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

Currently am working on the report. What i need is
sample table,

```
Instance Type   Sep-23  Sep-16  Sep-09  Sep-02  Aug-26  Aug-19
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Early ASN        4        2      4        1       1       2
Late ASN         2        1      5        3       1       1
     Sum         6        3      9        4       2       3
```

But the Actual Table is,

```
SPGI01_INSTANCE_TYPE_C  SPGI01_CREATE_S
--------------------------------------------------------------
Early ASN                9/17/2012 12:00:00.000
Early ASN           9/18/2012 10:06:11.000
Early ASN           9/19/2012 8:00:04.000
Early ASN           9/20/2012 3:00:05.000
Early ASN           9/10/2012 12:00:07.000
Early ASN           9/11/2012 12:00:32.000
Early ASN           9/3/2012 12:00:17.000
Early ASN           9/4/2012 10:06:00.000
Early ASN           9/5/2012 8:00:00.000
Early ASN           9/6/2012 3:00:00.000
Early ASN           8/31/2012 12:00:00.000
Early ASN           8/26/2012 12:00:00.000
Early ASN           8/14/2012 12:00:00.000
Early ASN           8/15/2012 12:00:00.000
Late ASN            9/17/2012 12:00:00.000
Late ASN            9/18/2012 10:06:00.000
Late ASN            9/11/2012 12:00:00.000
Late ASN            9/3/2012 12:00:00.000
Late ASN            9/4/2012 10:06:00.000
Late ASN            9/5/2012 8:00:00.000
Late ASN            9/6/2012 3:00:00.000
Late ASN            9/6/2012 2:00:00.000
Late ASN            8/31/2012 12:00:00.000
Late ASN            8/31/2012 12:00:00.000
Late ASN            8/31/2012 12:00:00.000
Early ASN           8/15/2012 12:00:00.000
```

I need to group by the "SPGI01_INSTANCE_TYPE_C" column and group the each week sunday upto last six week sundays.Here i pasted two sample tables one table is what i want and another table is what i have. Give me the solution for this.

My query is,

```
SELECT distinct I01.[SPGI01_INSTANCE_TYPE_C],
count (I01.[SPGI01_INSTANCE_TYPE_C])
  FROM [SUPER-G].[dbo].[CSPGI01_ASN_ACCURACY] I01,
  [SUPER-G].[dbo].[CSPGI50_VALID_INSTANCE_TYPE] I50

where
I01.[SPGA02_BUSINESS_TYPE_C] = 'prod'
and
I01.[SPGA03_REGION_C] in( 'ap','na','sa','eu')
and 
I01.[SPGI01_SUB_BUSINESS_TYPE_C] = 'PRD'
and
(I01.[SPGI01_CREATE_S] between '2012-01-01 12:00:00.000' AND DATEADD(day , 7, '2012-01-15 00:00:00.000'))

and
I01.[SPGI01_EXCEPTIONED_F] = 'N'
and
I01.[SPGI01_DISPUTED_F] != 'Y'
and
I50.[SPGI50_INSTANCE_TYPE_C] = I01.[SPGI01_INSTANCE_TYPE_C]
and 
I50.[SPGA04_RATING_ELEMENT_D] = 1
group by I01.[SPGI01_INSTANCE_TYPE_C]
```

Comment: As already stated, add some working query, does not matter it's wrong, is a starting point and maybe you are not far from the correct one.

Comment: You ask for `GROUP BY` Sundays but the dates you posted are Fridays, which is the correct date that you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a few assumptions about the data that you posted.

First, the values you posted all state the year as `2011` but the final end dates as column headers do not correspond to `2011`, they are the `Sunday` values for `2012` so I altered the data.  Also the final entry of `Early ASN  8/15/2011 12:00`, I believe is supposed to be a `Late ASN` entry otherwise the totals to do match up.

To get the results, you want you will want to apply the [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function. This function allows you to aggregate the values and then convert them to columns.

```
SET DATEFIRST 1 -- set this so the start of the week is Sunday
select InstanceType,
  sum([39]) as Sep_23, 
  sum([38]) as Sep_16, 
  sum([37]) as Sep_09, 
  sum([36]) as Sep_02, 
  sum([35]) as Aug_26, 
  sum([34]) as Aug_19
from
(
  select SPGI01_INSTANCE_TYPE_C as InstanceType,
    [39], [38], [37], [36], [35], [34]
  from
  (
    select SPGI01_INSTANCE_TYPE_C,
      DatePart(wk, SPGI01_CREATE_S) WeekNo,
      DATEADD(DAY, 7 -DATEPART(WEEKDAY,SPGI01_CREATE_S),SPGI01_CREATE_S) WeekEnd
    from table1
  ) x
  pivot
  (
    count(WeekEnd)
    for weekno in ([39], [38], [37], [36], [35], [34])
  ) p
) x1
group by InstanceType with rollup
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7d806/31)

Comment: Hi bluefeet, I have added my query.I need to join the two talbes and get these values.I hope it's easily to understood here.

Comment: @ThinkWhoiam then you should create a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with working data from both tables.

Comment: @ThinkWhoiam glad you figured it out. :)

Comment: i have another question about the query. i want the last six week sunday dates excluding currrent week for example system date is, Oct-05-2012.At this time i need the sep-23,sep-16,sep-9,sep-2,aug-26,aug-9. Is this same query returns what i want right?

Comment: @ThinkWhoiam all you need to do is use a `WHERE` clause to filter the data and then adjust the weeknumber values.

Comment: feet last question why you put [39], [38], [37], [36], [35], [34]. can i change this to [6], [5], [4], [3], [2], [1] ? is it really affects the real data ? can you explain that ?

Comment: @ThinkWhoiam that is the actual week number for the week when looking at the calendar. You have to give it a value to group by, I am using weeknumber so you can be sure that the dates are in the same time frame.

Comment: i checked it's working fine. You keep on moving man.I think god gave me the "stackoverflow" to share the knowledge here.At the same time you are priceless. Thank you for you time to spend my question.

Comment: hi @ bluefeet , how can i change the last value "null"  to "Sum"

Comment: @ThinkWhoiam use a `CASE` statement see this fiddle -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7d806/65

Comment: hi @blueFeet, i have one issue with this query. That is in my first column i have the value that is 'Sum'.I showed these all the values using the display tag in the jsp page using struts.But the 'Sum' value occurs in the middle of the row or otherwise shows second row. HOw can i set the 'Sum' value as last record in the display tag.

Comment: feet , can you refer this link please ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837970/how-can-i-set-a-record-as-last-using-displaytable

Comment: @ThinkWhoiam I am not familiar with how to display on a jsp page.

Comment: @ThinkWhoiam you need to post a new question

Comment: feet, if weekNo is more than [39] it doesn't show the count what can i do...please help me. For example now the weekNo is 46,44,42 it doesn't show me the count. Please give me the solution it suitable for the whole year.I'm waiting for your reply...

Comment: @ThinkWhoiam you will need to create a dynamic SQL version of this to get all of the weeks in the year otherwise you will have to hard-code every single value in the `PIVOT`. When I say hard-code I am referring to this piece `([39], [38], [37], [36], [35], [34])` - you will have to add the other weeks there, like this -- `([40], [39], [38], [37], [36], [35], [34], [33])`, etc.  If you need a dynamic version then post another question.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i can't post any question through this account. I don't it is blocked...

Comment: Can you please to refer my another account. i posted the same question there. Otherwise can you please suggest me the dynamic query for that. End of today i need to release my code. Could you please do it ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13623367/how-to-get-the-six-week-sunday-count-using-the-weekno-in-sql-2008