# How can I set a record as last using display:table?

Tags: jsp, jstl, jsp-tags, displaytag

I'm using a `display:table`, just to display tags. In my scenario I have 7 columns. For the first column, I get the values at runtime. For example I have these values in my `manualASNListUID.instanceType` that is an `arraylist(manualASNListUID)` and `object(instanceType)`. The column values are Early ASn, Late ASn, Sum. Otherwise Early Asn and Sum or else Early ASn, Late ASn, CMMS and Sum.

How can I set the 'Sum' values as display in the last row?

For example my table:

```
Instance Type   Sep-23  Sep-16  Sep-09  Sep-02  Aug-26  Aug-19 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Early ASN        4        2      4        1       1       2 
Late ASN         2        1      5        3       1       1     
Sum              6        3      9        4       2       3 

Instance Type   Sep-23  Sep-16  Sep-09  Sep-02  Aug-26  Aug-19 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Early ASN        4        2      4        1       1       2 
Late ASN         2        1      5        3       1       1  
CMMS             0        0      0        0       0       0   
Sum              6        3      9        4       2       3
```

My code is:

```
<display:table name="${weeklyDlvyInstancesDashboardReportForm.manualASNListQO}" uid="manualASNListUID" sort="list" defaultsort="1" requestURI="/weeklyDlvyInstancesDashboardReportPre.do?method=httpGet" excludedParams="method" decorator="com.ford.mpl.superg.decorator.WeeklyDeliveryInstancesTypeTableDecorator" keepStatus="true">
    <%@include file="/jsp/include/displaytag.jsp"%>
    <c:set value="${manualASNListUID.firstWeekOfCountLabel}" var="manualASNFirstWeekOfCount"/>
    <c:set value="${manualASNListUID.secondWeekOfCountLabel}" var="manualASNSecondWeekOfCount"/>
    <c:set value="${manualASNListUID.thirdWeekOfCountLabel}" var="manualASNThirdWeekOfCount"/>
    <c:set value="${manualASNListUID.fourthWeekOfCountLabel}" var="manualASNFourthWeekOfCount"/>
    <c:set value="${manualASNListUID.fifthWeekOfCountLabel}" var="manualASNFifthWeekOfCount"/>
    <c:set value="${manualASNListUID.sixthWeekOfCountLabel}" var="manualASNSixthWeekOfCount"/>
    <c:if test="${(manualASNListUID.instanceType != null && manualASNListUID.instanceType ne 'Sum')}">
    <display:column property="instanceType" title="Instance Type" sortable="false"/>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${(manualASNListUID.instanceType != null && manualASNListUID.instanceType eq 'Sum')}">
    <display:column property="instanceType" title="Instance Type" sortable="false" style="font-weight:bold;text-align:center"/>
    </c:if>
    <display:column property="${checkvalue}" title="Instance Type" sortable="false"/>
    <display:column property="${checkvalSum}" title="Instance Type" sortable="false" style="font-weight:bold;text-align:center"/>
    <display:column property="firstWeekOfCount" title="${manualASNFirstWeekOfCount}" sortable="false" autolink="true"/>
    <display:column property="secondWeekOfCount" title="${manualASNSecondWeekOfCount}" sortable="false"  autolink="true"/>
    <display:column property="thirdWeekOfCount" title="${manualASNThirdWeekOfCount}" sortable="false"  autolink="true"/>
    <display:column property="fourthWeekOfCount" title="${manualASNFourthWeekOfCount}" sortable="false" autolink="true" />
    <display:column property="fifthWeekOfCount" title="${manualASNFifthWeekOfCount}" sortable="false" autolink="true"/>
    <display:column property="sixthWeekOfCount" title="${manualASNSixthWeekOfCount}" sortable="false" autolink="true"/>
    </display:table>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. displaytag iterates over a list of rows. So if you want the sum row to be last, put it in the last position in the list.

Comment: @JB Nizet, i try and let you know that

Comment: @JB Nizet, i think you wrongly understood. The 'Sum' is not the column name, it's value that occurs in the list.

Comment: In the above table examples, the sums are all in the last row of the table. And a row of a displaytag table is an element of the List which constitutes the data of the table. So if Sum is the last row, you should have the object containing the sums as the last element of the list.

Comment: @JB Nizet, i tested but it's not working. do you have nay other idea to test that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<display:table name="${weeklyDlvyInstancesDashboardReportForm.manualASNListQO}" uid="manualASNListUID" sort="list" defaultsort="1" requestURI="/weeklyDlvyInstancesDashboardReportPre.do?method=httpGet" excludedParams="method" decorator="com.ford.mpl.superg.decorator.WeeklyDeliveryInstancesTypeTableDecorator" keepStatus="true">
    <%@include file="/jsp/include/displaytag.jsp"%>
    <c:set value="${manualASNListUID.firstWeekOfCountLabel}" var="manualASNFirstWeekOfCount"/>
    <c:set value="${manualASNListUID.secondWeekOfCountLabel}" var="manualASNSecondWeekOfCount"/>
    <c:set value="${manualASNListUID.thirdWeekOfCountLabel}" var="manualASNThirdWeekOfCount"/>
    <c:set value="${manualASNListUID.fourthWeekOfCountLabel}" var="manualASNFourthWeekOfCount"/>
    <c:set value="${manualASNListUID.fifthWeekOfCountLabel}" var="manualASNFifthWeekOfCount"/>
    <c:set value="${manualASNListUID.sixthWeekOfCountLabel}" var="manualASNSixthWeekOfCount"/>

    <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${asnAccuracyListUID.instanceTypeDescription != null && asnAccuracyListUID.instanceTypeDescription != 'Sum'}">
        <display:column property="instanceTypeDescription" title="Instance Type" sortable="false"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <display:column property="instanceTypeDescription" title="Instance Type" sortable="false" style="font-weight:bold;text-align:center"/>
    </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>

    <display:column property="${checkvalue}" title="Instance Type" sortable="false"/>
    <display:column property="${checkvalSum}" title="Instance Type" sortable="false" style="font-weight:bold;text-align:center"/>
    <display:column property="firstWeekOfCount" title="${manualASNFirstWeekOfCount}" sortable="false" autolink="true"/>
    <display:column property="secondWeekOfCount" title="${manualASNSecondWeekOfCount}" sortable="false"  autolink="true"/>
    <display:column property="thirdWeekOfCount" title="${manualASNThirdWeekOfCount}" sortable="false"  autolink="true"/>
    <display:column property="fourthWeekOfCount" title="${manualASNFourthWeekOfCount}" sortable="false" autolink="true" />
    <display:column property="fifthWeekOfCount" title="${manualASNFifthWeekOfCount}" sortable="false" autolink="true"/>
    <display:column property="sixthWeekOfCount" title="${manualASNSixthWeekOfCount}" sortable="false" autolink="true"/>
    </display:table>
```