# How to get the description from the tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot, pivot-table

I got this query with the help of @Blue Feet. But the below query i have the instance type and in addition to that i need the instance type description from another tables.So i need to make a join with extra two tables.

```
Table - RelationShips:
------------------------
Table Name                          Column Name                 Key
CSPGI50_VALID_INSTANCE_TYPE         CSPGI50_INSTANCE_TYPE_C     Primary
CSPGJ02_MSG_OBJ                     CSPGJ02_MSG_K               Primary 
CSPGI03_MANUAL_ASN                  CSPGI03_ASN_C                primary
CSPGJ03_MSG_TRANSLN                 CSPGJ03_LOCALE_C              primary   

Column Having tables:
------------------------------
CSPGI50_VALID_INSTANCE_TYPE(CSPGJ02_MSG_K,CSPGI50_INSTANCE_TYPE_C)
CSPGJ03_MSG_TRANSLN(CSPGJ02_MSG_K)
CSPGI03_MANUAL_ASN(CSPGI03_INSTANCE_TYPE_C)
CSPGJ02_MSG_OBJ(CSPGJ02_MSG_K)
```

i have this below query,

```
SET DATEFIRST 1  
SELECT 
    case when InstanceType is not null then InstanceType else 'Sum' End InstanceType , 
    sum([39]) AS FirstWeek, 
    sum([38]) AS SecondWeek,   
    sum([37]) AS ThirdWeek, 
    sum([36]) AS FourthWeek, 
    sum([35]) AS FifthWeek, 
    sum([34]) AS SixthWeek  
FROM 
(
    SELECT [SPGI03_INSTANCE_TYPE_C] AS InstanceType, 
        [39], [38], [37], [36], [35], [34]  
    FROM 
    ( 
        SELECT I03.[SPGI03_INSTANCE_TYPE_C],  
            DatePart(wk, I03.[SPGI03_CREATE_S]) WeekNo, 
            DATEADD(DAY, 7 -DATEPART(WEEKDAY,I03.[SPGI03_CREATE_S]),
            I03.[SPGI03_CREATE_S]) WeekEnd  
        FROM [SUPER-G].[dbo].[CSPGI03_MANUAL_ASN] I03, [SUPER-G].[dbo].[CSPGI50_VALID_INSTANCE_TYPE] I50  
        where I50.[SPGI50_INSTANCE_TYPE_C] = I03.[SPGI03_INSTANCE_TYPE_C] 
            and  I50.[SPGA04_RATING_ELEMENT_D] = 2 
            and I03.[SPGI03_EXCEPTIONED_F] = 'N'  
            and I03.[SPGI03_DISPUTED_F] != 'Y'  
            and I03.[SPGI03_CREATE_S] between '08-19-2012 12:00:00.000' AND DATEADD(day , 7, '09-30-2012 11:59:59.000' 
    )) x 
    pivot 
    ( 
        count(WeekEnd) 
        FOR weekno IN ([39], [38], [37], [36], [35], [34])  
    ) p 
) x1 
GROUP BY  InstanceType WITH ROLLUP
```

### What i want:

I want to add the Instance Type Description from the

```
Table 2-column name([SPGJ03_MSG_TRANSLN_X])
```

If you have doubt please refer my previous query link
[How to group by the each week upto last six week sundays dates in sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12743869/how-to-group-by-the-each-week-upto-last-six-week-sundays-dates-in-sql)

Comment: @bluefeet, i created the another question regarding my query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to tell how the tables are related, but it looks like you want to do something like this:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1  
SELECT 
    case when InstanceType is not null then InstanceType else 'Sum' End InstanceType , 
    sum([39]) AS FirstWeek, 
    sum([38]) AS SecondWeek,   
    sum([37]) AS ThirdWeek, 
    sum([36]) AS FourthWeek, 
    sum([35]) AS FifthWeek, 
    sum([34]) AS SixthWeek,
    max(InstanceDescription)
FROM 
(
    SELECT [SPGI03_INSTANCE_TYPE_C] AS InstanceType, 
        [39], [38], [37], [36], [35], [34], InstanceDescription
    FROM 
    ( 
        SELECT I03.[SPGI03_INSTANCE_TYPE_C],  
            DatePart(wk, I03.[SPGI03_CREATE_S]) WeekNo, 
            DATEADD(DAY, 7 -DATEPART(WEEKDAY,I03.[SPGI03_CREATE_S]),
            I03.[SPGI03_CREATE_S]) WeekEnd,
            J03.SPGJ03_MSG_TRANSLN_X InstanceDescription
        FROM [SUPER-G].[dbo].[CSPGI03_MANUAL_ASN] I03
        INNER JOIN [SUPER-G].[dbo].[CSPGI50_VALID_INSTANCE_TYPE] I50  
          ON I50.[SPGI50_INSTANCE_TYPE_C] = I03.[SPGI03_INSTANCE_TYPE_C] 
        LEFT JOIN CSPGJ02_MSG_OBJ J02
          ON I50.SPGJ02_MSG_K = J02.SPGJ02_MSG_K
        LEFT JOIN CSPGJ03_MSG_TRANSLN J03
          ON J02.SPGJ02_MSG_K = J03.SPGJ02_MSG_K
        where I50.[SPGA04_RATING_ELEMENT_D] = 2 
            and I03.[SPGI03_EXCEPTIONED_F] = 'N'  
            and I03.[SPGI03_DISPUTED_F] != 'Y'  
            and I03.[SPGI03_CREATE_S] between '08-19-2012 12:00:00.000' AND DATEADD(day , 7, '09-30-2012 11:59:59.000' 
    )) x 
    pivot 
    ( 
        count(WeekEnd) 
        FOR weekno IN ([39], [38], [37], [36], [35], [34])  
    ) p 
) x1 
GROUP BY  InstanceType WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: @ThinkWhoiam can you create a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with the tables and then some sample data?

Comment: feet,i updated the relationship, in the meanwhile time i try there.But if i can't solve that.Please help me..

Comment: i checked the above query but it filter more datas, my required data not get.

Comment: previously i got the correct number of values.but it differs from the previous query..i need the same output of previous query in addition to that i just want to add the instance type description.i there any way to solve this ?

Comment: @ThinkWhoiam it is difficult to say what the problem is without seeing data for each table.  create a sql fiddle with a working data model.

Comment: feet, if weekNo is more than [39] it doesn't show the count what can i do...please help me. For example now the weekNo is 48,43,40 it doesn't show me the count. Please give me the solution it suitable for the whole year.I'm waiting for your reply

Comment: feet, What i need is, get max(weekno),max(weekno-1),max(weekno-2),max(weekno-3),max(weekno-4),max(weekno-5)

Comment: @ThinkWhoiam you will need to create a dynamic SQL version of this to get all of the weeks in the year otherwise you will have to hard-code every single value in the `PIVOT`. When I say hard-code I am referring to this piece `([39], [38], [37], [36], [35], [34])` - you will have to add the other weeks there, like this -- `([40], [39], [38], [37], [36], [35], [34], [33])`, etc.  If you need a dynamic version then post another question.

Comment: Could you please add the dynamic query ..because without i finished this task. the delivery might be pending..sorry for asking..this

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13623367/how-to-get-the-six-week-sunday-count-using-the-weekno-in-sql-2008

Comment: i'm waiting for your reply, because i have the only one chance to get this