# How to get the six week sunday count using the Weekno in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to group by the each week upto last six week sundays dates in sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12743869/how-to-group-by-the-each-week-upto-last-six-week-sundays-dates-in-sql)

I need to take the count of weekno. It works fine but i don't know the weekno that is [34],[35],[36],[37],[38],[39]. The weekno knows only on the runtime.For example in a year it contains totally 52 weeks. I got this query from the help of @Bluefeet, he posted the query on the same stackoverflow. If i change the from date and to date in the between field it doesn't work. Because i hard coded the weekno in the below query. Please give me the solution whatever the date in the between field within the year.

```
SET DATEFIRST 1 
SELECT case when InstanceType is not null then InstanceType else 'Sum' End InstanceType ,  
  sum([34]) AS FirstWeek, 
  sum([35]) AS SecondWeek, 
  sum([36]) AS ThirdWeek, 
  sum([37]) AS FourthWeek, 
  sum([38]) AS FifthWeek, 
  sum([39]) AS SixthWeek,  
  max(InstanceDescription) AS InstanceDescription 
FROM 
( 
  SELECT [SPGI01_INSTANCE_TYPE_C] AS InstanceType, 
    [34], [35], [36], [37], [38], [39], InstanceDescription  
  FROM 
  ( 
    SELECT I01.[SPGI01_INSTANCE_TYPE_C], 
      DatePart(wk, I01.[SPGI01_CREATE_S]) WeekNo, 
      DATEADD(DAY, 7 -DATEPART(WEEKDAY,I01.[SPGI01_CREATE_S]),  I01.[SPGI01_CREATE_S]) WeekEnd, 
      J03.SPGJ03_MSG_TRANSLN_X InstanceDescription  
    FROM [SUPER-G].[dbo].[CSPGI01_ASN_ACCURACY] I01  
    INNER JOIN [SUPER-G].[dbo].[CSPGI50_VALID_INSTANCE_TYPE] I50 
      ON I50.[SPGI50_INSTANCE_TYPE_C] = I01.[SPGI01_INSTANCE_TYPE_C]  
    LEFT JOIN CSPGJ02_MSG_OBJ J02 
      ON I50.SPGJ02_MSG_K = J02.SPGJ02_MSG_K  
    LEFT JOIN CSPGJ03_MSG_TRANSLN J03 
      ON J02.SPGJ02_MSG_K = J03.SPGJ02_MSG_K  
    where I50.[SPGA04_RATING_ELEMENT_D] = 1  
      and I01.[SPGI01_EXCEPTIONED_F] = 'N' 
      and I01.[SPGI01_DISPUTED_F] != 'Y'  
      AND J03.[SPGJ03_LOCALE_C] =  'en_US'  
      and I01.[SPGA02_BUSINESS_TYPE_C] = 'PROD'  
      and I01.[SPGA03_REGION_C] = 'EU'  
      and I01.[SPGI01_SUB_BUSINESS_TYPE_C] = 'PRD'  
      and I01.[SPGI01_CREATE_S] between '10-08-2012 00:00:00.000' AND '11-18-2012 23:59:59.000'  
  ) x 
  pivot 
  ( 
    count(WeekEnd) 
    FOR weekno IN ([34], [35], [36], [37], [38], [39])  
  ) p 
) x1 
GROUP BY  InstanceType WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: What programming language are you using in the runtime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are looking to be able to pass in any date values to get the data that meets your criteria, then for this type of `PIVOT` you will need to use a dynamic SQL solution similar to this:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsRollup AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @StartDate DateTime,
    @EndDate DateTime

Set @StartDate = '10-08-2012 00:00:00.000'
Set @EndDate = '11-18-2012 23:59:59.000'

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(WeekEnd) 
                    from
                    (
                      select DatePart(wk, I01.[SPGI01_CREATE_S]) WeekEnd
                      from [SUPER-G].[dbo].[CSPGI01_ASN_ACCURACY]
                      where I01.[SPGI01_CREATE_S] between @StartDate AND @EndDate
                    ) src
                    group by WeekEnd
                    order by WeekEnd desc
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

select @colsRollup = STUFF((SELECT ', Sum(' + QUOTENAME(WeekEnd) +') as WeekNo'+Cast(Weekend as varchar(2))
                    from
                    (
                      select DatePart(wk, I01.[SPGI01_CREATE_S]) WeekEnd
                      from [SUPER-G].[dbo].[CSPGI01_ASN_ACCURACY]
                      where I01.[SPGI01_CREATE_S] between @StartDate AND @EndDate
                    ) src
                    group by WeekEnd
                    order by WeekEnd desc
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = '
             SELECT case when InstanceType is not null then InstanceType else ''Sum'' End InstanceType ,  
                '+@colsRollup+',  max(InstanceDescription) AS InstanceDescription
             FROM
             (
               SELECT SPGI01_INSTANCE_TYPE_C as InstanceType,
                    InstanceDescription, ' + @cols + ' 
               from 
               (
                  SELECT I01.[SPGI01_INSTANCE_TYPE_C], 
                    DatePart(wk, I01.[SPGI01_CREATE_S]) WeekNo, 
                    DATEADD(DAY, 7 -DATEPART(WEEKDAY,I01.[SPGI01_CREATE_S]),  I01.[SPGI01_CREATE_S]) WeekEnd, 
                    J03.SPGJ03_MSG_TRANSLN_X InstanceDescription  
                  FROM [SUPER-G].[dbo].[CSPGI01_ASN_ACCURACY] I01  
                  INNER JOIN [SUPER-G].[dbo].[CSPGI50_VALID_INSTANCE_TYPE] I50 
                    ON I50.[SPGI50_INSTANCE_TYPE_C] = I01.[SPGI01_INSTANCE_TYPE_C]  
                  LEFT JOIN CSPGJ02_MSG_OBJ J02 
                    ON I50.SPGJ02_MSG_K = J02.SPGJ02_MSG_K  
                  LEFT JOIN CSPGJ03_MSG_TRANSLN J03 
                    ON J02.SPGJ02_MSG_K = J03.SPGJ02_MSG_K  
                  where I50.[SPGA04_RATING_ELEMENT_D] = 1  
                    and I01.[SPGI01_EXCEPTIONED_F] = ''N'' 
                    and I01.[SPGI01_DISPUTED_F] != ''Y''  
                    AND J03.[SPGJ03_LOCALE_C] =  ''en_US''  
                    and I01.[SPGA02_BUSINESS_TYPE_C] = ''PROD'' 
                    and I01.[SPGA03_REGION_C] = ''EU''  
                    and I01.[SPGI01_SUB_BUSINESS_TYPE_C] = ''PRD''
                    and I01.[SPGI01_CREATE_S] between '+ convert(varchar(10), @StartDate, 120)+' AND '+ convert(varchar(10), @EndDate, 120)+'
              ) x
              pivot 
              (
                  count(WeekEnd)
                  for weekno in (' + @cols + ')
              ) p 
             ) x1
             GROUP BY InstanceType WITH ROLLUP '

execute(@query)
```

*Note: this is untested since I do not have any sample data, etc.*

Comment: what i'm asking is, you posted the query @cols,@colsRollup,@query then execute(@query). Can i run one by one or copy the entire query and then to run. what do you mean by @...Is it store like object ?

Comment: @AdalarasanSachithanantham those are variables, you need the entire thing to run the query successfully

Comment: where can i give the start date and end date in the above query ?

Comment: the column is growing...but it doesn't show me the answere

Comment: Please create a sql fiddle with your tables and some sample data

Comment: i don't know how to use the SQL fiddle, please give me some suggestions to use it

Comment: i attached the screen shot for your clear understandin

Comment: The screenshot is not helpful -- see this sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1fa93/1 -- edit it with your information

Comment: ok thanks i will take care of that..

Comment: how can i get the weekno using the from date and to date. Do you have idea about that ?

Comment: @AdalarasanSachithanantham I don't understand your question.

Comment: first i run the separate query using the from date and to date. Then i fed into the input of the weekno to my previous query.

Comment: My question, for example the given month (november) and given date (11/18/2012).Then i need the weekno for the November month 18 that is 46. So i take the 46 to give the input of my previous query and less -1,-2,-3,-4,-5 thats it (46,46-1,46-2,46-3,46-4,46-5).

Comment: It is not based upon the data whether it present or not. Why because sometimes it present and sometimes it won't.

Comment: @AdalarasanSachithanantham It may surprise you to learn that everyone on this site contributes their time voluntarily and is not compensated for their efforts.  Being demanding of someone giving their own time to try to assist you is not productive and would be considered by some (most) to be very rude.